# Is there a way for Twitter4J to verify credentials by only using consumer key and secret?

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I'm working on an Android App which allows users to configure Twitter consumer key and secret by themselves (Access Token and Access Token Secret are not configured). I want to verify key and secret like below before showing login page, but it throws an exception:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(key, secret);
        try {
            User user = twitter.verifyCredentials(); // this line throws an exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The exception is:

> Twitter credential verification fails.java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Authentication credentials are missing. See
>   http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details

Is there a way to verify the consumer Key and Secret without Access Token and Access Token Access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception message that you encounter is pretty clear:

> Authentication credentials are missing.

You need to authenticate correctly first, before trying to access the Twitter API programmatically. Using only `setOAuthConsumer(key, secret)` does not set/configure necessary access token information. Both information needs to be provided (*Hint*: If you're interested in it, [this introduction](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor9) gives you an overview on how the *OAuth* authentication works).

According to http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html you can then initialize the code via a `ConfigurationBuilder` instance like so:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
  .setOAuthConsumerKey("*your-consumer-key*")
  .setOAuthConsumerSecret("*your-consumer-secret*")
  .setOAuthAccessToken("*your-access-token*")
  .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*your-access-token-secret*");
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
```

Given valid a *AccessToken*/*AccessTokenSecret*, you should then be able to call:

```
try {
    User user = twitter.verifyCredentials(); 
    // ... do further things....
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @MWiesner. My intention was to check if key and secret are valid or not. I realize that I can check that by calling this: Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();  twitter.setOAuthConsumer(key, secret);  twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(); If key and secret are invalid, it will throw exception when calling twitter.getOAuthRequestToken().